# How to install polyglot on Raspberry Pi? - problems with compatibility

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2, polyglot

I want to install this on my Raspberry Pi 2 (Raspbian):
http://polyglot.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Installation.html

Unfortunately, when I did `sudo pip install polyglot` I got the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip install -U git+https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot.git@master
Downloading/unpacking git+https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot.git@master
  Cloning https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot.git (to master) to /tmp/pip-97dbqD-build
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-97dbqD-build/setup.py) egg_info for package from git+https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot.git@master

    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory '*'
Downloading/unpacking futures>=2.1.6 (from polyglot==15.10.03)
  Downloading futures-3.0.5-py2-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking PyICU>=1.8 (from polyglot==15.10.03)
  Downloading PyICU-1.9.2.tar.gz (175kB): 175kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-FkLuG4/PyICU/setup.py) egg_info for package PyICU

Downloading/unpacking pycld2>=0.3 (from polyglot==15.10.03)
  Downloading pycld2-0.31.tar.gz (14.3MB): 14.3MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-FkLuG4/pycld2/setup.py) egg_info for package pycld2

Requirement already up-to-date: morfessor>=2.0.2a1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Morfessor-2.0.2alpha3-py2.7.egg (from polyglot==15.10.03)
Downloading/unpacking six>=1.7.3 from https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/s/six/six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=3ab558cf5d4f7a72611d59a81a315dc8 (from polyglot==15.10.03)
  Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking wheel>=0.23.0 from https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/w/wheel/wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=d7db45db5c131af262b8ffccde46a88a (from polyglot==15.10.03)
  Downloading wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66kB): 66kB downloaded
Installing collected packages: futures, PyICU, pycld2, six, wheel, polyglot
  Running setup.py install for PyICU
    building '_icu' extension
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c dateformat.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/dateformat.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    In file included from dateformat.cpp:24:0:
    common.h:33:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Python.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-FkLuG4/PyICU/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-kNR6VT-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7

copying icu.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7

copying PyICU.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7

copying docs.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7

running build_ext

building '_icu' extension

creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7

arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c dateformat.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/dateformat.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"

cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++

In file included from dateformat.cpp:24:0:

common.h:33:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include <Python.h>

                    ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-FkLuG4/PyICU/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-kNR6VT-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-FkLuG4/PyICU
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 248, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 42: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I believe this is a problem with PYCLD2? It is for 64bit system?
How to solve this problem?

@edit

After executing: `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

I got:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip install polyglot
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): polyglot in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/polyglot-15.10.03-py2.7.egg
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): futures>=2.1.6 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from polyglot)
Downloading/unpacking PyICU>=1.8 (from polyglot)
  Downloading PyICU-1.9.2.tar.gz (175kB): 175kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-y6_Rht/PyICU/setup.py) egg_info for package PyICU

Downloading/unpacking pycld2>=0.3 (from polyglot)
  Downloading pycld2-0.31.tar.gz (14.3MB): 14.3MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-y6_Rht/pycld2/setup.py) egg_info for package pycld2

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): morfessor>=2.0.2a1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Morfessor-2.0.2alpha3-py2.7.egg (from polyglot)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.7.3 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from polyglot)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): wheel>=0.23.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from polyglot)
Installing collected packages: PyICU, pycld2
  Running setup.py install for PyICU
    building '_icu' extension
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c dateformat.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/dateformat.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c char.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/char.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c errors.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/errors.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c numberformat.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/numberformat.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c charset.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/charset.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c normalizer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/normalizer.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c transliterator.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/transliterator.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c unicodeset.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/unicodeset.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c shape.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/shape.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c collator.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/collator.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _icu.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/_icu.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c iterators.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/iterators.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c tzinfo.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/tzinfo.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c search.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/search.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c layoutengine.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/layoutengine.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c calendar.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/calendar.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c idna.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/idna.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c spoof.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/spoof.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c common.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/common.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    common.cpp: In function ‘void _stopDecode(const void*, UConverterToUnicodeArgs*, const char*, int32_t, UConverterCallbackReason, UErrorCode*)’:
    common.cpp:62:32: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
             const int len = length < sizeof(stop->chars) - 1 ? length : sizeof(stop->chars) - 1;
                                    ^
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c format.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/format.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c regex.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/regex.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c locale.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/locale.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    locale.cpp: In function ‘int t_locale_init(t_locale*, PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
    locale.cpp:323:21: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
                 if (len < sizeof(code))
                         ^
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c bases.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/bases.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c script.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/script.o -DPYICU_VER="1.9.2"
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    c++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-z,relro -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/dateformat.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/char.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/errors.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/numberformat.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/charset.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/normalizer.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/transliterator.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/unicodeset.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/shape.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/collator.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/_icu.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/iterators.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/tzinfo.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/search.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/layoutengine.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/calendar.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/idna.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/spoof.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/common.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/format.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/regex.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/locale.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/bases.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/script.o -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -licule -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/_icu.so

  Running setup.py install for pycld2
    building 'pycld2._pycld2' extension
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Icld2/internal -Icld2/public -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c cld2/internal/cldutil.cc -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/cld2/internal/cldutil.o -w -O2 -m64 -fPIC
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-m64’
    error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-y6_Rht/pycld2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-pSIInS-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7

creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/pycld2

copying pycld2/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/pycld2

running build_ext

building 'pycld2._pycld2' extension

creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7

creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/cld2

creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/cld2/internal

creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/bindings

arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Icld2/internal -Icld2/public -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c cld2/internal/cldutil.cc -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/cld2/internal/cldutil.o -w -O2 -m64 -fPIC

arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-m64’

error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-y6_Rht/pycld2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-pSIInS-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-y6_Rht/pycld2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 248, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 42: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: This error seems to show up when `python-dev` is missing. Have you tried `sudo apt-get install python-dev`?

Comment: I did what you said and I'm still getting `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-m64’`. I updated my question.

Comment: You were correct in your guess that it is 64bit. Simliar thread https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=17574.. but for the -m32 flag

Comment: But did you mean, that I cannot install this at all or maybe there is some way to install this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem.

First you need to do is to download polyglot's source code:

```
git clone https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot
```

Then edit setup.py:

```
nano polyglot/pycld2/setup.py
```

Change this line:

```
extra_compile_args=['-w', '-O2', '-m64', '-fPIC'],
```

to:

```
extra_compile_args=['-w', '-O2', '-fPIC'],
```

Install PYCLD2:

```
sudo ./setup.py install
```

Install polyglot:

```
cd ..
sudo ./setup.py install
```

Comment: pycld2 is now at https://github.com/aboSamoor/pycld2 - it's not (any more?) under polyglot repo